# Is there any side effect in using \immediate in the definition of \protected@write?

Tags: auxiliary-files, write

In `latex.ltx`, `\protected@write` is defined as:

```
\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
```

Is there any side effect in using `\immediate` before `\write` in the definition of `\protected@write`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you change this in `\protected@write` the side effects are severe. For example, `\protected@write` is used in `\label`. The page number is not known right away in general. The delay of the `\write` without `\immediate` writes the entry at page shipout time, when the page number is known.

Thus **do not change** `\protected@write`. If you need immediate writing, use a new macro instead and do not use it for page numbers and such things that are reliably correct at shipout time only.